# `read` builtin does not preserve input that is whitespace only

Tags: bash, input

I am trying to read a keystroke input from the keyboard and assign it to a variable `key`. I am using `read` as follows:

```
read -sn1 key && echo "${#key}" "\"$key\"" "${key:?}"
```

This reads a single character (aka keystroke) from the keyboard and sets `key` to that character and echos info about `key`. If I type a readable character (`d`), it will show, for example:

```
1 "d" d
```

But if I type a tab or space, I get (from the last part of the `echo` statement):

```
bash: key: parameter null or not set
```

However, if I use the default `REPLY` and hit the space bar, it works as expected when I hit the space bar:

```
$ read -sn1 && echo "${#REPLY}" "\"$REPLY\"" "${REPLY:?}"
1 " "
```

Also, if I explicitly specify `REPLY` as the name of the variable to use, explicitly, it does not work as the last example showed, instead, it fails as when I used `key`.

```
$ read -sn1 REPLY && echo "${#REPLY}" "\"$REPLY\""
0 ""
```

What's going on? It seems like specifying a `name` to `read` to store the results to cause it to lose whitespace-only input. (I verified this by removing `-n` and entering longer whitespace-only input).

Comment: Normally, `read` does not preserve whitespace.  If you want `read` to preserve whitespace, set `IFS` to empty like: `IFS= read -sn1 key && echo "${#key}" "\"$key\"" "${key:?}"`.

Comment: It preserves whitespace if either the default symbol, `REPLY` is used, or the whitespace contains some non-whitespace. Without `-n`, I can enter `"1  b"` and the whitepace is preserved. You prompted further test to refine my conclusions, above. If I specify the name, leading/trailing whitespace is stripped. If I use the default `REPLY` (but, unspecified), leading/trailing whitespace is preserved.

Comment: Indeed, clearing `IFS` looks to make the behavior consistent whether the symbolname is specified or not. Thank you. It still seems like a bug, no?

Comment: It's not a bug. Your example is specifically losing leading and trailing whitespace, which is discarded during word-splitting. Setting `IFS=` disables word-splitting, as does using the default name `REPLY`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`read` performs word-splitting on the line it reads in order to set the variables provided as its arguments. As part of word-splitting, any leading or trailing whitespace is discarded; other whitespace is retained if splitting isn't required to produce the requested number of fields. For example,

```
$ read a b <<< " foo bar      baz  "
$ echo "=$a="
=foo=
$ echo "=$b="
=bar      baz=
```

Because only two fields are requested, the whitespace between `bar` and `baz` is left alone.

Wordsplitting occurs even if only one name is used.

```
$ read a <<< "   foo       bar    "
$ echo "=$a="
=foo       bar=
```

There are two ways to disable word-splitting:

1. Unset or clear the value of `IFS`. This retains all leading/trailing whitespace and assigns the entire line to the first name given as an argument.
2. A `bash` extension uses the name `REPLY` if no name arguments are provided to `read`; word-splitting is not performed before assigning the input to `REPLY`.

Answer (score 4):

Here's `help read`:

> The line is split into fields as with word
>       splitting, and the first word is assigned to the first NAME, the second
>       word to the second NAME, and so on, with any leftover words assigned to
>       the last NAME.  Only the characters found in $IFS are recognized as word
>       delimiters.
>
> If no NAMEs are supplied, the line read is stored in the REPLY variable.

You'll notice that this means that `read` is *not* the same as `read REPLY`.

When you specify a name argument, word splitting will occur (even if it's just one). If you don't specify a name, the line is simply stored in `REPLY` as-is, i.e. without any word splitting. This is how the single space survives.